# First isomorphism theorem in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\phi : X \to Y$ be a linear map and suppose further $\phi$ is onto, then there is an isomorphism $$X/ker\phi \approx \phi(X) = Y.$$

This can be seen in the finite dimensional case via the rank-nullity, but is there another justification? I recall there is one, but i can't write it out.

EDIT: Actually such a map $\psi:X/\ker\phi \to \phi(X)$ can be defined via the natural map $\psi (x + \ker \phi) = \phi(x).$ It is certainly one to one because $\psi(y + \ker) = \psi(x + \ker) \iff\phi(x) = \phi(y) \iff \phi(x - y) = 0 \iff z = x - y \in ker\phi \iff z + \ker \phi = \ker \phi \iff x + \ker = y + \ker $

Comment: This can be proved by hand:  if $[x] \in X/\ker \phi$ denotes the coset of $x \in X$, then the isomorphism is defined by $f([x]) = \phi(x)$.  You can check that $f$ is well-defined (i.e. doesn't depend on the choice of a representative $x$), linear, and is a one-to-one and onto map from $X/\ker \phi$ to $Y$.  This is essentially the proof of rank-nullity in the finite-dimensional case, but it works just as well for infinite-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 6):

This is a rather fundamental result which holds for many homomorphisms between certain "structures": groups, rings, modules, etc. (vector spaces are a special case of the latter).

The "intuition" is that the kernel of a linear map can be thought of as the "redundancy" carried by the map: how much information from the original space do we lose through this mapping. The canonical isomorphism is given by mapping the cosets of the kernel in our original space onto the image of the linear map defined via the orginal linear map in the obvious way. This map is clearly bijective since we have "removed" elements which are mapped to zero and nothing more. Our original linear map is now decomposed into two parts, the quotient map from the original space onto the quotient (which now encodes the redundancy of the original map), and an isomorphism.

The rank-nullity result is a special case of this, and is the result of checking the dimensions of each of the vector spaces considered.

Comment: mind reading my argument?

Comment: You should also mention that the map is well-defined, but this is actually done via the chain of equivalent facts. Also justify that it is a bijection. There are a couple of typos, but otherwise it is mostly there.